# Changing the color of numbers and special words in listings for a Python snippet

Tags: color, listings, python, keywords

I'm using the listings package to write a report where I report some code in Python that I used. I am not very familiar with listings and am having several problems. Specifically:

1. I would like to have the numbers in blue color (for example). Following some examples found on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ I was able to change their color. However, some of the variables have numeric codes inside them that change color.
2. There are some words (i.e., the names of method parameters) that I would like to change in color. For example product=, latitude=, longitude=, band=, km_above_below=, km_left_right=, I would like them to be in orange. I'm really struggling to figure out how to do this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{codeorangered}{RGB}{239,134,64}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Codice}

\lstdefinelanguage{Python}
{
  keywords={from, import, def, return, as, for, if, in, len},
  keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
  keywords=[2]{product=, latitude=, longitude=, band=, km_above_below=, km_left_right=}
  keywordstyle=[2]{\color{codeorangered}},  
  commentstyle={\color{codegreen}},   
  morecomment=[l]{\#},
  morestring=[b]",
  alsodigit={-},
  alsoletter={&}
}



\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    language=Python,
    backgroundcolor={\color{backcolour}},   
    commentstyle={\color{codegreen}},
    keywordstyle={\color{magenta}},
    keywordstyle=[2]{\color{codeorangered}},    
    numberstyle={\tiny\color{codegray}},
    stringstyle={\color{codepurple}},
    basicstyle={\ttfamily\footnotesize},
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,  
    %otherkeywords={product=, latitude=, longitude=, band=, km_above_below=, km_left_right=},
    %keywords=[2]{product=, latitude=, longitude=, band=, km_above_below=, km_left_right=}, 
    %frame=single,                    
    tabsize=2
}





\lstset{
    style=mystyle
}


%
\newcommand\digitstyle{\color{blue}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ProcessDigit}[1]
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode\relax%
   {\digitstyle #1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\lstset{literate=
    {0}{{{\ProcessDigit{0}}}}1
    {1}{{{\ProcessDigit{1}}}}1
    {2}{{{\ProcessDigit{2}}}}1
    {3}{{{\ProcessDigit{3}}}}1
    {4}{{{\ProcessDigit{4}}}}1
    {5}{{{\ProcessDigit{5}}}}1
    {6}{{{\ProcessDigit{6}}}}1
    {7}{{{\ProcessDigit{7}}}}1
    {8}{{{\ProcessDigit{8}}}}1
    {9}{{{\ProcessDigit{9}}}}1
    {<=}{{\(\leq\)}}1,
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[b]',
    morecomment=[l]//,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=Snippet example. ]
from nasawebservice import *
# Create a MODIS data provider 
provider = NasaWebServiceAPIProvider(base_url="https://modis.ornl.gov")
# APPLICATION 1: retraive all data in the NASA's archive
archive = provider.async_execute_all(
    product=Products.MOD13Q1,
    latitude=44.04780019, longitude=10.35481917,
    band=Bands.MOD13Q1.NDVI,
    km_above_below=0, km_left_right=0
)
for item in archive: print(item)
# APPLICATION 2: get the last data if present
if provider.is_present(Products.MOD13Q1, 44.04780019, 10.35481917, "A2022081"):
        last = provider.last_product(
        product=Products.MOD13Q1, 
        latitude=44.04780019, longitude=10.35481917, 
        band=Bands.MOD13Q1.NDVI
        km_above_below=0, km_left_right=0
    )
    print(last)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```